# How to connect LEDs to D+ and D- of USB 3.0 cable

Tags: led, communication, cables, usb-c, data

I need to connect LEDs to USB 3.0 cable that connect to PC and to embedded device.
I want visual control to see data transfer by this USB cable and want to connect LEDs for this purpose, like Ethernet connector in PC or another device which have two LEDs. Of cause it must not interfere with transfer data process between PC and embedded device.

How I can do this?

Comment: You cannot do that. USB doesn't work the way you think it does. Not only is the signaling sensitive to the interference which attaching LEDs would cause, but USB signaling is *always* active - even when there's no data being transferred.

Answer (score 9):

In easy terms, you cannot.

Driving LED's straight from D+ or D- won't give you any usable information at all. Any communication on the USB will happen way too fast for your eyes to recognize. Also, there is pretty much always some activity on the data lines as long as there is an active connection.

What I´d recommend is that you use some outputs on your embedded device, and flash those at some point when data transfer is being done.

That's pretty much how the Ethernet LED's you mentioned, works. They are connected to dedicated outputs on the Ethernet PHY, not directly to the data lines.